# Efficient code for screencap adb with python

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, adb

I have this code, it works like I expect:

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep

# Run the command and capture the stdout
COMMAND = 'adb exec-out screencap -p'

FRAME_COUNT = 0
while 1:
  with open(f'./frames/frame_{FRAME_COUNT}.png', 'wb') as file:
    stdout, stderr = subprocess.Popen(COMMAND,
                                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    # Store the byte stdout in a variable
    file.write(stdout)
  sleep(1)
  FRAME_COUNT += 1
```

But I'm doubting about efficiency of code, mainly `Popen`. Every iteration, it's creating instance `Popen`, is it okay for memory?, Any idea for better solution?

Update, I added opencv:

```
import subprocess
import cv2
import numpy as np
from time import time

COMMAND = 'adb exec-out screencap -p'

while True:
  tLast = time()

  # Capture the screen using adb
  png_stdout_bytes = subprocess.check_output(COMMAND)

  # Convert the stdout bytes to a numpy array
  png_bytes = np.frombuffer(png_stdout_bytes, np.uint8)

  # Decode the image from the numpy array
  img = cv2.imdecode(png_bytes, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

  # Resize the image to be 50% smaller
  width = int(img.shape[1] * 0.45)
  height = int(img.shape[0] * 0.45)
  resized_img = cv2.resize(img, (width, height))

  fps = 1 / (time() - tLast)
  cv2.putText(resized_img, f'FPS: {fps:.2f}', (10, 30),
              cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

  # Display the resized image
  cv2.imshow('Screen Capture', resized_img)
  cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: If you want to capture a lot of screen shots (or evan a video) you may better check the source code of [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) how they implement live view of the Android screen.

Answer (score 0):

One viable alternative for most applications is to use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

ViewClient.view_client_helper().ui_device.take_screenshot(filename="mysc.png")
```

You can see full examples at [screenshot](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/examples/helper/screenshot) or [take-screenshot](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public/blob/master/take-screenshot) using two similar approaches.